# Work with New Branch in Separate Folder (Git)

Tags: git, directory, branch

I started a new project in Eclipse, created a new branch of an existing project, and downloaded the project into the Eclipse project folder. The purpose is that I need to maintain two versions of the same software.

Is it possible to work with different folders corresponding to different branches? How can I achieve this?

For example, I would like to push new versions to `Master` only, while working in `develop`. However, I still want to have different folders locally.

I could use Git command line or Eclipse Team, but ideally I would like to work with the GitHub app for windows as much as possible. I have considered the alternative to keep separate versions in separate Git respositories, but this is not as feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to use a single repository with branches. This is what branches are meant for.

But why do you want separate folders for different branches?
You can easily switch from one branch to the other: you just code on one branch, commit, checkout the other branch

If you absolutely need to have the two branches checked out at the same time you will have to clone the repository two times, in two different folders and checkout one branch in each folder.

Comment: I guess the issue was that I did not separate distribution from development as I am developing software for inhouse use.